# Is my Statement and Branch coverage correct?

Tags: code-coverage

```
def score_report(scores):
     '''print a report on exam scores
     args: scores - a list of numbers representing exam scores
     returns: nothing
     '''
     sum = 0.0
     for score in scores:
       if score > 0.0:
         sum += score
     if len(scores) > 0:
       mean = sum / float(len(scores))
       print("the mean score is {0}".format(mean))
       if (mean > 50):
         print("on average, people passed. Yay!")
     else:
       print("No scores were found")
```

If  my understanding is correct, in order to achieve 100% statement coverage but not achieve 100% branch coverage for `score_report` my test inputs for `score_report` would be `[100], []`
Is this correct? The reason I ask is 100% statement coverage is supposed to use one input to cover all statements and I've used two. I'm not sure if this is my mistake.

Furthermore, the smallest set of test inputs to this method that achieve 100% branch coverage would be `[100], [], [-1]`
Is this also correct?